# Create an object from a class name

Tags: java, class, object

I have a String array that contains my classes names , and i want that every loop i create an object from the class name in the array to get methods from it,

```
String[] namesArray = new String[3];
namesArray = {"Circle","Triangle","Ellipse"}
for(int i=0; i<namesArray.length(); i++){
    String s = namesArray[i];
    //here i want to create an object from s
}
```

i have tried this method

```
String className = "TestReflection";
String fullPathOfTheClass = "eg.edu.alexu.csd.oop.draw." + className;
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fullPathOfTheClass);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {  });
```

but it gives me that error

[image]

Comment: I don't see how you can get that exception with your code. When I test it, the error is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments". Which is perfectly expected since you get the constructor taking a String but invoke it with no parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw `NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException` in your method, like:

```
void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException
```

and There is another issue existing in your code.

```
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {  });
```

Your constructor set `String` as parameter, but when you call `newInstance`, you are setting an empty `Object` array as parameter. Maybe:

```
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { "String Parameter" });
```